# Unity UI Objects edges are not smooth

Tags: unity, gui, image, unity-ui

I have this Unity UI Image placeholder and here is the snapshot
[image]
 As you can see its edges are not smooth. First I thought this is editor problem but after making the build it remains the same. What i am missing?

Comment: looks like you have an object that's rotated ever so slightly relative to the screen grid. Can you show us how you've set this up in your scene? Walk us through the steps to reproduce this in a new empty project.

Comment: yes, you are right my parent object z position was slightly changed. Setting this to zero solve the problem . can you write the answer with some explanation?

Comment: The same content has loaded with resources folder

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory, the reason was

> looks like you have an object that's rotated ever so slightly relative
>   to the screen grid.

My UI elements z rotation was slight rotated so I change it to zero and it solved the problem.